# Relation between the class $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ and subgaussianity

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505175), Adamczak defines, for $m>0$ and $\sigma\geq 0$, the class of probability distributions $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ as those $\mu$ satisfying the tail conditions
$$\nu^+([x,\infty)) \leq \mu([x,\infty)),\quad \nu^-((-\infty,-x]) \leq \mu((-\infty,-x])$$
for every $x\geq m$, where $\nu^+,\nu^-$ are the measures with densities $g^+(x) = x\mu([x,\infty)$ and $g^-(x) = -x\mu((-\infty,-x])$, respectively.
(See Definition 4, or [the followup work by Adamczak and Strzelecki](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05493) which generalizes the results of the first paper)

The paper also proves (Lemma 2) that the condition $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ implies $C(m,\sigma)$-subgaussianity for some constant $C(m,\sigma)$. Some more examples are given, but I am not fully seeing how this class $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ is related to subgaussianity:

> How much stricter is the condition $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ than subgaussianity? Are there "natural" examples of subgaussian distributions which are not in $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$ for any $m,\sigma$?

Moreover, in view of one of the main results of the paper, Theorem 3 (the log-Sobolev inequality for convex functions holds for measures in $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$):

> Is it known whether the subgaussian concentration inequality in Theorem 3 fails for some random variables which are sugaussian but not in any $\mathcal{M}(m,\sigma)$?

Comment: Such an inequality (the 2nd one in Theorem 3 of the first paper) holds for $\varphi(X)$ when $\varphi:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz and $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ has iid sub-Gaussian coordinates. This follows from Lévy's inequality combined sub-G concentration (to further bound the Lévy concentration function of the situation). The details can be found in standard  text like Boucheron et al *Concentration inequalities.* So my guess is that the authors in your referenced paper only need those conditions to bound the Lévy concentration function, which can be done via other assumptions.

Comment: @dohmatob interesting -- thanks. I guess what I'm missing in your comment is the bound on the concentration function for subgaussian (looking at the Boucheron et al. book, I couldn't find it for subgaussian, just for Gaussian or Hamming wrt weighted Hamming). I should probably go back to that book...

Comment: I was referring to Theorem 7.1 of  the book, which holds for any metric space (including Hamming cube), but the real question is bounding $\alpha(t)$.  To this end, If you take as definition of sub-Gaussian vector to mean the distribution satisfies a $T_1$ inequality (T for Talagrand), then you can use Theorem 3.1 of (S. Bobkov) https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf. Finally, otherwise, if $\psi$ is $1$-Lipschitz w.r.t $L_1$ distance, you can used results from this paper (A. Kantorovich
) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1007.pdf. I hope any of this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those asap!

Comment: Erratum: The correct link to S. Bobkov's paper (Theorem 3.1) is this one https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf